# Adobe Encore CS4 DVD menu button not functioning

Tags: dvd, authoring, adobe-creative-suite

I've built a DVD in Adobe Encore CS4, and everything works great in the preview. However, when I go and burn to DVD, we have one issue.

On the DVD menu, there are two text buttons, with no background when unselected, and have a background when selected. That allows the user to know which is selected.

Like I said, everything works great in the preview, but the background that is supposed to appear when the button is selected does not. The buttons work, but there is no background when selected. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you test it on more DVD-players? And the DVD-player in your PC? I got the same problem, but it is not with all dvd players..

Answer (score 0):

We were able to solve the problem. Another member of our team recreated the project from scratch, and it worked. Not sure what the problem was, but everything works now.

Thanks,
Jack